# How Can i hide the MainActivity while pop up AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to hide `MainActivity` when `AlertDialog` is shown.
I create new Activity and put my code in it and call it from `MainActivity` by using `Intent`.

**My Code of `AlertDialog` :**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Dialog extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dialog.this);
        builder1.setTitle("RONQ");
        builder1.setMessage(MainActivity.mesgList.get(MainActivity.currentMsgNumber));
        builder1.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        builder1.show();

    }
}
```

**And `Intent` code is :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Dialog.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **Intent**:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("message")
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.update), (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                                    //do something
                                }).setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), (dialogInterface, i) -> {
//do something 
    }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
```

Comment: Not do what i want !!!
I want to hide the back activity and show dialog only.

Comment: Mohammed Alloboany ?

Comment: So try dialog activity

Comment: Do u want to replace AlertDialog To Dialog Activity?

Comment: or create new activity and make it as a dialog?

Comment: Yes and finish the main, https://javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/